# How to override inherited styles? is the only way to redefine all styled elements?

Tags: html, css

Say I have my CSS like this:

```
div.some-class table
```

So I have:

```
<div class="some-class">

<table ...>
..
</table>
</div>
```

Now if I need to have a child div inside the table, **the child seems to inherit from the parent style**, and I want this to be styled differently.

```
 <div class="some-class">

    <table ...>


    <div> <table .. > ... </table> .. </div>


    </table>
    </div>
```

how do I do this?  do I have to be explicit and do this:

```
div.some-class table div.other-class table
```

Any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `.other-class{...}` if you're trying to style the div itself, or `.other-class table {...}` if you want to style the table.

Answer (score 0):

You should always be explicit.  It makes things easier to understand:

```
div.some-class table                           { /* styles */}
    div.some-class table div.other-class table { /* child-styles */}
```

Either that or use an `#id` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could

- give the first table a specific class name and have all rules point to that class (this is the easiest solution but the least nice in terms of clean CSS)
- Use the child selector `div.some-class > table` to create rules that address only the first table and not the second one ([doesn't work in IE6](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html))

Comment: can you explain the first option?

Comment: @Blankman  `<table class='firstlevel'>` .... and then `div.some-class table.firstlevel {....}`